# Interpreting the eigenvectors/eigenvalues of a "spelling co-occurrence" matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix $S$ of *spelling co-occurrences*: for example, the word "ace" shares two letters with "axe", so the matrix entry corresponding to ("ace", "axe") will have a value of $2$. This is a symmetric matrix, and along the diagonal of $S$ are the number of letters of each word (e.g., the element ($i$,$i$) would corresponding to the number of letters shared between a word $i$ and itself). Therefore, if we apply the original transformation $S$ to a one-hot vector $\mathbf{w}$ that is $1$ at $i$ and $0$ elsewhere,  it returns the spelling co-occurrences of word $i$ with every other word.

I was curious about whether the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of this matrix have an interesting interpretation. If we apply $S$ to an eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$ instead of the one-hot word vector $\mathbf{w}$, this vector is scaled by the corresponding eigenvalue. But what would this mean? Is there a non-geometric interpretation for it?